# Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=f(x+1)=f(x+\pi)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Show that $f(x)$ is constant.

Tags: analysis

> Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=f(x+1)=f(x+\pi)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Show that $f(x)$ is constant.

By the condition, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)=f(x+k(\pi-1)),\quad k\in\mathbb Z.
\end{eqnarray*}

My thought is that suppose $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$, then by appropriate $k_1$ and $k_2$, we may get $x_1+k_1(\pi-1)$ and $x_2+k_2(\pi-1)$ closed enough to ensure that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$ is arbitrary small. But I don't know how to show this, or this method cannot work.

Comment: This has something to do with the irrational nature of $\pi$.

Comment: I have thought about this, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Since you cannot write both $1$ and $\pi$ as a multiple of any number, the only other way to satisfy the given equation is if $f$ is a constant. Perhaps edit into your post what you know about periodic functions and if you still need help writing a proof, someone here can help you move forward.

Comment: All this says is that $f$ is periodic with period $\pi - 1$, which does not imply that $f$ is constant -- e.g. you can take $f(x) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{\pi - 1} x)$. Are you sure this is the given condition? If the condition was instead that $f(x) = f(x+1) = f(x + \pi)$ for all $x$, that would force $f$ to be constant.

Answer (score 1):

$f(k+n\pi)=f(k+n)$ since $\{k+n\pi\}$ is dense, the image of $f$ is contained in $f(\mathbb{Z})$ so it countable, the intermediate value theorem implies that it is constant.

Comment: Thanks. This will solve the problem. But how to show $\{k+n\pi\}$ isdense?

Comment: because it is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ which is either discrete or dense.